# onClick() get a new value from function passed to Django template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a function in `views.py` that generate random characters, then the generated characters gets passed to the template in `index` view. In the template I have `change` button that should generate a new random characters but it doesn't do that. It changes whatever value in the field to the generated characters already passed to the template.

Here in the template `btn1` should change the default `{{ random }}` value to a new value every time it gets clicked.

index.html

```
<form method="POST">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="{{ random }}" onclick="this.select()" readonly="readonly">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" id="btn1" class="btn btn-default" onClick="document.getElementById('name').value='{{ random }}'">Change</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Find</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

views.py

```
def generate(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    random = generate()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NamesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            return redirect(checkingNames, name=name)
    else:
        form = NamesForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'random': random})
```

Comment: here you are directly assigning the random value which generated before you have call the random value generated function script when the button is clicked then it has to run the script again

Comment: How can I get the script to run when the button is clicked?

Comment: use `load` function in jquery

Comment: I read about `load` and it accepts a `url` as a parameter. Is there a way to pass the function `generate()` from `views.py`?

Comment: include in the header `<?php include 'yourfile.php';?>` and call the generate function directly when the button is clicked

Comment: @JohnAnkanna What does this anything to do with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You should use javascript to make changes on page async.
You have 2 ways.

1. If generating is going to be safe use AJAX. On click you should send
   ajax-request to server, which will give you new random for some data
2. If it's not going to be safe(as in example) you can generate random string just by javascript. For example, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript)